# Strange Winston issue with File transport open and closing

Tags: node.js, npm, winston

I've been having a strange issue with Winston and was looking for some guidance. I am trying to rotate logs by simply closing the file stream using

```
myTransport.transports.file.opening = true;
myTtransport.transports.file.close();
```

then opening it back up using

```
myTransport.transports.file._createStream();
```

I tried to use

```
myTransport.transports.file.open();
```

But that didn't work as expected after looking at the code.  My problem is the I get a

```
events.js:45
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: EBADF, Bad file descriptor
```

error once the file is closed, renamed, then opened back up again.  Here is [a link](http://www.screencast.com/t/xsXEypoUuD) to a video showing the behavior.  In file.js (file transport) after createAndFlush (line 229) is done and self.flush (line 255) is returned.  The next execution jumps straight to return `return self.emit('error', err);` (line 261).

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.  I've been working on this for a few says now and can't seem to find anything about it on here or any other board.  I know winston has maxFile size and maxFiles, but this will not work for our needs.  Thanks.

-Steve